# Entity Framework Takes a longer time to get the response the first time using within the same context

Tags: entity-framework

I am having an issues with the EF that the first query takes a long time. I thought the query itself was taking a long time. So, I used

```
context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

to see what query is being sent. It only took only 1 ms but from the open connection to close connection, it took 18 second. The following is the message from the debug message.

```
**Opened connection at 3/19/2015 9:25:49 PM +06:30 
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ItemId] AS [ItemId], 
    [Extent1].[SerialNumber] AS [SerialNumber], 
    [Extent1].[SimNumber] AS [SimNumber], 
    [Extent1].[ItemStatusId] AS [ItemStatusId], 
    [Extent1].[StoreId] AS [StoreId]
    FROM [dbo].[ItemDetail] AS [Extent1]
-- Executing at 3/19/2015 9:25:49 PM +06:30
-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader
    Closed connection at 3/19/2015 9:26:07 PM +06:30**
```

Within the same context, another query similar to the previous one was sent. It only took 1 second from the Open to Close connection.

```
**Opened connection at 3/19/2015 9:26:10 PM +06:30

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ItemId] AS [ItemId], 
    [Extent1].[SerialNumber] AS [SerialNumber], 
    [Extent1].[SimNumber] AS [SimNumber], 
    [Extent1].[ItemStatusId] AS [ItemStatusId], 
    [Extent1].[StoreId] AS [StoreId]
    FROM  [dbo].[ItemDetail] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Item] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ItemId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ItemStatusId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[CategoryId] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[StoreId] = @p__linq__2)


-- p__linq__0: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__1: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__2: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 3/19/2015 9:26:10 PM +06:30

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Closed connection at 3/19/2015 9:26:11 PM +06:30**
```

Why does the first query take longer time to close the connection?

I know that the first query usually take time because of loading the meta data. But this is different that the open connection and executing query are so close and after getting the results, it takes a long time to close the connection in the first query.

Comment: Doesn't the first query return a lot more data?

Comment: How is your database generated? If you're using EF Code First, the first query is probably either a) generating the database itself, or b) validating that the database model matches the code model.

Comment: Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327(v=vs.100).aspx for all the things EF does once per app-domain on startup.

Comment: Please show the code that executes the first query and processes the results.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details of your code, the only factor I can come up with is that it matters how a LINQ query is processed. One thing in particular that can cause a connection to remain open relatively long is enumerating a LINQ query and executing some time-consuming process in each iteration:

```
var details = from d in ItemDetail
              where ...
              select new { ... }

foreach (var detail in details)
{
    // DbDataReader reads a record on each iteration
    SomeLengthyProcess(detail);
}
// Connection is closed after the last iteration.
```

Here's a sample output (leaving out some irrelevant details)

```
Opened connection at 09:48:33

SELECT statement

-- Executing at 09:48:33

-- Completed in 14 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
Record5

Closed connection at 09:48:37
```

Which shows that the statement itself is executed in "no time", but that it takes another 4s for the reader to produce each record.

The way to make the connection close sooner is:

```
foreach (var detail in details.ToList())
```

which builds an in-memory list first and then iterates over it. In this case, the connection closes immediately after the "Completed" logging line.